# c# ExportToExcel creates corrupted xlsx file

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I'm using the following library:

http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm

Here is my code:

```
private void exportExcelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There's nothing to export", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return;
    }

    DataTable save = Utilities.DataGridView2DataTable(dataGridView1, "TestingReport");

    string outputFile = Utilities.saveDoc(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), save);
    if (outputFile != null)
    {
        DialogResult opt = MessageBox.Show("Export successful. Would you like to view the file?", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        if (opt == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(outputFile);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this same exact code in two different projects, however in one project the excel files it creates are corrupted/unreadable.

When extracting the contents of the .xlsx file, the first thing I notice is that the `[Content_Types].xml` file present in the working project isn't in the output from the project that isn't working. Also, the workbook.xml files created are both 0kb whereas the working project files actually have data in them.

I have tried doing `Console.WriteLine`.

I'm also using this code to convert my `DataGridView` to a `DataTable` so it can be written to excel: https://www.crealoq.com/solved/how-to-convert-datagridview-to-datatable-using-csharp

I've gone through and added `Console.WriteLine(...)` to verify that data is actually being returned from this function and everything looks fine.

EDIT:

The only difference I've noticed is that when I click the button to save the excel, and then choose NOT to view it right then, when I go to unzip the excel document, the app that returns a valid excel document lets me unzip it, however when I try to unzip the one that ISN'T working, it says the file is currently opened..

Answer (score 0):

If your first column header is called "id" that could be causing problems. You can try prepending "`" to any column called "id"

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I had changed a part of code in `CreateExcelFile.cs`

[image]

This had the same effect as not closing a StreamWriter after being finished with it, and then missing a bunch of text because of that. I changed this block of code b/c it wasn't working without the WindowsBase.dll. After referencing that DLL and changing the code back I'm able to successfully export my datagridview to excel

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar, also with a DataGridView.

First I get the values from the column I need(in my case it was only 1 column)

```
List<float> values = new List<float>();

for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
   valores.Add(float.Parse(valoresMonitoreo[0, y].Value.ToString()));
```

Then the export function

```
private void export()
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
            object misvalue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

          try
          {
              oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
              oXL.Visible = true;
              oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open(libro));
              oWB.Sheets[x].Select(); 
              //x is the number of the sheet where you want to save data.
              oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

//This goes into a for
oSheet.get_Range(tmp, misvalue).Value2 = values[x]; //tmp is a string, which contains letter and number of the cell "A1". misvalue is an object variable
    oWB.Save();
                    oWB.Close();
                    oXL.Visible = false;
                    oXL.UserControl = false;
                    oXL.Application.Quit();
    }
    catch(Exception exc){}
    }
```

You must use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try Flushing and Closing the HttpResponse request. This worked for me.

```
response.OutputStream.Flush();
response.OutputStream.Close();
response.Flush();
response.Close();
```